# Audio EQ that is light on resources

Tags: sound, equalizer

Pulseeffects looks great but on an older Pentium 4 computer running Lubuntu 18.10 it is barely useable when streaming from the web.

I just want an EQ (about 10 bands) that is light on resources. I do not need all those other FX included in Pulseeffects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I should add that with a 64-bit computer (with slightly better processor and ram), Pulseeffects works fine. Maybe I was just pushing the Pentium 4 to its limits. Also, there is a Pulse Mutliband EQ which looks lighter but I can't get it to work with the latest versions of Lubuntu.

Comment: You just have to power-off (unclick) any FX you don't want to use inside the left list of PulseEffects. In your case, you have to put the [On-Off] switch in the top of each FX you don't want in the [Off] position. Only the EQUALIZER switch has to be [On]. You can select the number of bands of the EQ, too.